# codeblock on scientifics linux

Tags: linux, codeblocks

Good morning,

could anyone please help me understand why after opening codeblock on Linux scientific and having chosen the console, during the compiling it keeps on saying that it can't find g++ and it doesn't run the compiling phase? We are pretty sure we inserted C as language and Gcc as compiler in the initialization phase. Thanks for your help!

```
---------------Build: DEbug in <File_name> ( compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ----------------------

g++ -o bin/Debug/<file_name> obj/Debug/main.o

/bin/sh: g++: command not found

Process terminated with status 127 ( 0 minute(s) , 0 second(s)
0 error(s), 0 warning(s) ( 0 minute(s) , 0 second(s)
```

Comment: Have you installed the GCC C++ compiler?

Comment: Haven't used gcc in a while, however, gcc was C compiler, not C++. I kinda remember gcc and g++ were sort of linked, but I presume the relevant C++ packages are missing if you only selected C as language and gcc as compiler.

Comment: yes i have installed the compiler but i have to compile in c and not in c ++ the problem is that codeblock is looking for g ++

Comment: I'll explain the problem: 
I open codeblock and choose the console set the C language and the respective GCC compiler, when I open the blank page and try to compile it writes to me what I have specified before you as there is a bug !! in short, as that even if I imposed the language c and gcc he read g ++ as a compiler ...

Answer (score 0):

It isn't failing in the compilation.

This:

```
g++ -o bin/Debug/<file_name> obj/Debug/main.o
```

is the *linkage*. You only get this far if *compilation* has completed successfully.

You have installed only the GCC C toolchain and not GCC C++, perhaps because you only
want to program in C, which is perfectly reasonable.

However, Code::Blocks default configuration assumes that you have both C and C++,
and it calls `g++` to execute the linkage step *in C projects as well as C++*
projects.

This is the simplest default, because the resulting linkage options will work
for exclusively C++ projects of course; they will also work for exclusively C language projects,
and they'll also work for mixed C/C++ language projects. *But only if you have
installed* `g++`. If you haven't, then of course linkage fails:

```
/bin/sh: g++: command not found
```

If you don't need C++ you will never need to link C++ projects or mixed C/C++
projects. Then you can easily fix the problem:

- Navigate from the top menubar
  **Settings** -> **Compiler** -> **Global compiler settings** (Selected compiler =
  GNU GCC compiler) -> **Toolchain executables** -> **Program files**
- Change the **Linker for dynamic libs** from `g++` to `gcc`
- OK out

Then your linkage will work.

If you *do* need C++ for other projects, then leave the settings as they are and install the GCC C++ toolchain.

Comment: I followed the information and the error is gone, but now when I try to compile and run it tells me this :                                                                   it seems that this project has not been built yet. do you want to build it now

Comment: sh: /home/luciano/Scrivania/lola/bin/Debug/lola: File or directory not existe    process returned 127(0x7F) execution time : 0.0003 s  press enter to continue

Comment: @LucianoCastori Clean your project: **Build** -> **Clean**. Then build it: **Build** -> **Build**
(not **Build and run**). Then copy-paste the *complete*
build log into the body of your question (not in comments). You will find the build log in the **Build log** tab (not the **Build messages**
tab)

Comment: Please can You post a configuration of a linker ??? Because are not present